# Azure Marketplace Application: Is it secure to putting password to ARM file?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-marketplace

I created Managed Application for Azure Marketplace. And I use some secret data during deploy app to user subscription. Is it secure putting this data to file `mainTemplate.json`? And if not, what variants exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/key-vault-access

The template files for a managed app in the marketplace are only secured by obscurity (you need to guess at what the URL is (and it contains a guid)).  So for added security, put the secrets in KV and reference them from there.

Comment: Can Managed Application's ARM read values from key-vault in my subscription if it deploying from Marketplace?

Comment: they can by the looks of it @FiftiN but you would have to hardcode kv secret reference into the template, right? there is no way user can know your kv secret url, right? but that means you need a nested deployment inside the template just to fetch it? yeah, sorry, didnt read that to the end

Comment: the more i think about it, the more i think that this is a weird concept. whatever you pass from the KV the user can extract from the resource, right? even if he cant (very rare occasions), user can create a marketplace solution that would do that, so its kinda pointless (not that this is easy, but doable)?

Comment: In question in my comment I meat such scheme: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/914224/51757089-56a81880-20e4-11e9-8a02-8153bb6139c3.png . Is it possible?

Comment: Yes the Managed App RP can read the secret due to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/key-vault-access#add-service-as-contributor - the customer deploying cannot read the secret (unless you were to give them explicit access to it)

Answer (score 2):

not a good practice. Instead use Azure key vault as per your scenario.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis

Comment: how do you think that is supposed to work during marketplace deployment?

Comment: ok, turns out it might work, not that the poster knew that, but

Comment: I asked about it on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55026